# How do I make my current installation of 12.04 like when I first installed it?

Tags: 12.04, installation, uninstall, dependencies

I recently did a project involving a lot of messy installs. After manually undoing what evil I have done I realize I have broken a lot of dependencies and instead of manually slaving over each one, I'd like to 'go back in time', before I messed up my installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this news will come too late, but it will be of use next time: you *would* have been able to return to your old situation -- as a matter of fact, to *switch* between the mess and your pristine Ubuntu -- if you had set up a root jail (using e.g. `pbuilder`) before starting to mess about.

However, not all is lost. From `/var/log/apt/` you should be able to trace the packages you installed. An `apt-get --purge remove` of all of these should get you back to just where you were. That's one of the good things of the Debian packaging system.

If your mucking about involved not only `apt-get install`s, but also `sudo make install`s, then your luck depends somewhat on how well that software was packaged. Do however try the corresponding `sudo make uninstall`s. And remind yourself again to next time set the installation prefix to `/usr/local` :-/